# Override ToString() of not user's class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, overriding, tostring

I need to override `.ToString()` method of `XElement`.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without creating a new derived type from the class, you cant override a method like that. I would recommend taking a look at writing an extension method instead. [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).